# How to select something from JOIN? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: cities and students. Each student has city_id which references a city in the citites table.
I have a join:

```
SELECT lastname, city, points_avg
FROM students INNER JOIN cities
ON students.city_id = cities.city_id where city LIKE 'Paris'
```

It works pretty well.
But then, I want to select the student with the highest score EXCLUSIVELY from Paris.
I tried this:

```
select lastname, points_avg from (
    SELECT lastname, city, points_avg
    FROM students INNER JOIN cities
    ON students.city_id = cities.city_id where city LIKE 'Paris'
) AS join_name where points_avg = (select MAX(points_avg) from join_name);
```

But it says that current database doesnt have the table *join_name*

I wrote this:

```
select lastname, points_avg from (
    SELECT lastname, city, points_avg
    FROM students INNER JOIN cities
    ON students.city_id = cities.city_id where city LIKE 'Paris'
) AS join_name where points_avg = (select MAX(points_avg) from (
        SELECT lastname, city, points_avg
        FROM students INNER JOIN cities
        ON students.city_id = cities.city_id where city LIKE 'Paris'
    ) AS join_name_new);
```

And unexpectedly, it works, but it`s so stupid ahah

Could you advise me, how to get the same result without repeating join twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a CTE, but not a subquery:

```
with join_name as (
      select s.lastname, c.city, s.points_avg
      from students s join
           cities c
           on s.city_id = c.city_id
      where c.city like 'Paris'
     )
select jn.lastname, jn.points_avg
from join_name jn
where jn.points_avg = (select max(jn2.points_avg) from join_name jn2);
```

If you are learning SQL, that is just the difference between a CTE and a subquery.

Also note the use of table aliases and qualified column references.  They make it clearer what the query is really doing.

Also, I retained the structure of your query, but you `rank()` would be a more typical way to implement this logic.

Comment: Hi  i have doubt.  "SELECT lastname, city, points_avg
FROM students INNER JOIN cities
ON students.city_id = cities.city_id where city LIKE 'Paris' ORDER BY  points_avg DESC" The first row will be the highest score Isnt it.... OR Am i misunderstnanding the question

Comment: Yes, it is, but I need not to just order, I need to select) @IndraKumarS

Answer (score 1):

@Cognosce, if you are learning SQL then @Gordon Linoff is correct!

However, a much simpler way to write same query without subquery and CTE would be:

```
select s.lastname, c.city, s.points_avg
      from students s join
           cities c
           on s.city_id = c.city_id
      where c.city like 'Paris'
Order by s.points_avg desc
Limit 1
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, your solution is much more rational comparing to what I tryed doing.